# AzSK ARM Checker Task are not giving scanning results for Virtual Machine ARM Template

Tags: security, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

Am working on ARM Templates,Azure DevOps CI & CD and Secure DevOps Kit for Azure(AzSK). In my organisation, I created a build pipeline for scanning Virtual Machine ARM Template with the help of AzSK ARM Template Checker. Here, am facing some issue like "after the build triggered, at the time of scanning "Its skipping the checking Virtual Machine ARM Template and giving No controls have been evaluated for file" output through Excel File,logs. Can you please suggest me to "How to overcome this issue?"

I followed the [link](https://github.com/azsk/DevOpsKit-docs/tree/master/03-Security-In-CICD)

[image]

> Update-1

I think according to the document, there is no ARM Checker scanning for the Virtual Machine and it is for only few resource templates only. Is it true and got this point from the [Link-1](https://github.com/azsk/DevOpsKit-docs/tree/master/03-Security-In-CICD)

[image]

Comment: probably means it cannot check anything in the template?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Thank you for your reply. In that case, how to check/scan my ARM Template with the help of AzSK DevOps Kit

Comment: @4c74356b41 Please, once see the updated question

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you.
So if I'am correct and you click on the "ARM template for reference are available [here](https://github.com/azsk/DevOpsKit-docs/tree/master/ARMTemplates)" you can see the resources of arm templates that will be checked and there you can see virtual machine in the list.
But like my problem for the keyvault it still gives the same error. probably because the apiVersion is not updated.
I hope you find a solution for your problem and you are willingly to share it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @achahbar. You are able to get results after updating APIversion KeyVault. Is it working?

Comment: It's my bad, I didn't explain it well. 
I mean that in the ARM template checker if you look at the reference link in the readme.md the keyvault it is being showed as reference has stil an old api version

Comment: Yes, but the ARM templates which was ready now to check them are "App Service, Storage, SQL, CDN, Traffic Manager, Document DB, Redis Cache, and Data Lake" remaining are in still preview. So that the reason, why your KeyVault showing an error like that.

Comment: ow yeah that would be the reason indeed.
Any idea when the preview will be rolled out in production ?

Comment: @Mani do you have any clue where to contact the AZsk team to ask if this is on the road map; because this is a huge miss